# webView.canGoBack() always false

Tags: java, android, webview, android-webview, browser-history

I have a problem with Android Web View. 
When I override the function shouldOverrideUrlLoading in my class that extends WebViewClient then `WebView.canGoBack()` returns always `false`.

Below is my code

```
public class SMWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

   @Override
   public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
      view.loadUrl(request.getUrl().toString());
      return true;
   }

   @Override
   public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String uri) {
      view.loadUrl(uri);
      return true;
   }
}
```

And in the my activity:

```
@BindView(R.id.main_webview) SMWebView webView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    ...
    webView.setWebViewClient(new SMWebViewClient(){
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url){

        }
    });
    webView.clearCache(true);
    webView.clearHistory();
    webView.loadUrl(Constant.baseUrl + Constant.homeUrl);
}
```

The problem is that the function `webView.canGoBack` (always in my activity) returns always `false`:

```
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
       //ALWAYS FALSE
       if (webView.canGoBack()) {
          webView.goBack();
       }
    }
```

If I don't override shouldOverrideUrlLoading, than onBackPressed works as expected. What is wrong in my code?

Thanks

**[EDIT]:** I also tried (without success) to create webViewClient in this way:

```
ebView.setWebViewClient(new SMWebViewClient());
```

Answer (score 7):

There seems to be a problem with current release of Chrome (63+).
I downloaded Chrome Dev (65+), change the default webview to Chrome Dev 65+, the webview.canGoBack() works fine.

Here is some reading of bug reported:
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=794020

Chrome Dev download URL:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.chrome.dev

Changing default webview:
https://www.chromium.org/developers/androidwebview/android-webview-beta

Looks like we need to wait for somewhile for the new Chrome stable update.

Comment: And here I thought I was going insane. Thanks for the information.

Answer (score 2):

Do not load the url everytime in the `WebClient` this clears the past history of the `WebView` and also check how you extended the `WebView` to your own `SMWebView`.

Comment: Thanks @Xenolion for suggestion but nothing changes returning false.

Comment: But why do you want to set a webclient?

Comment: Because each time you give your webview another url!

Comment: I have to set WebViewClient to manage loading of some PDF file.
Without setting WebViewClient all works fine.

Comment: Yeah I have even edited my answer! So I think your question now is the best way to implement your feature! Tell me in detail well what you want to do so that I can suggest what you have to do!

Comment: Ok, @Xenolion I will try to explain better.
I have extended `WebView` in order to send some cookies to server in each request.
I have extended `WebViewClient`in order to manage some links that returns PDF.
The problem is in shouldOverrideUrlLoading: if I just returns `false` withou use call `view.loadUrl()` then history works fine but cookie are not sent. If I use `view.loadUrl(uri)` cookies are sent but history doesn't work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161365/discussion-between-xenolion-and-fciri).